# Angular: Controller as syntax not updating data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this code

template

`{{  GC.objectList }}`

Controller

```
var self = this;
self.objectList = [];


           myService.list().then(function (data) {
                self.objectList = data.results;
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            })
```

Now when i get new data from server then my data dont get updated in template.

However if use $scope instead of self. Then it works fine

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Please post your markup and if possible a demo reproducing this issue.

Comment: Can you console.log(self.objectList[]) after you call myService.list()? I think the variable is empty. You have tp return data.results and set it afterwards. Like self.objectList = myService.list().then(function(data) {return data;});

Comment: @gruberb i did that and object is populated with data. only issue is its not updated in template. It works if i use $scope.objectList and use {{ objectList}} in template but not with self. I thought self is same as scope but i may be wrong . may be $scope is used in that scenario

Answer (score 0):

Anything that needs to have an effect with respect to the view in Angularjs   or with respect to the manipulation should be done making use of the **$scope** obj. It is like you play with **$scope** which is created as a new instance for every controller created.

So hence making use of **$scope** is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

$scope is an object which is two way dynamic is a functionality providing you by angularjs. $scope will help you in assigning variables to the objects and if you are changing in the template, it will automatically get reflected in the scope object also.

Comment: i thought self will also do the same